# Animated UILabel disappears when returning from background

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel

I have UILabel that fades in and out repeatedly, but when app returns from background the text disappears.

I tried the following, but it didn't work,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fadeText), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}
```

```
    func fadeInThenOut(label : UILabel, delay: TimeInterval) {

         UILabel.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: delay, options: [UILabel.AnimationOptions.autoreverse, UILabel.AnimationOptions.repeat], animations: {
            view.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)

    }

@objc func fadeText() {
        fadeInThenOut(label: textLabel, delay: 0)
    }

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        fadeText()

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but could you try to remove the the animation from the button when the app enters background using button.layer.removeAllAnimations().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change **`willEnterForegroundNotification`**  to  **`didBecomeActiveNotification`** like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fadeText), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Then your selector should have an initial alpha value for self.view:

```
  @objc func fadeText() {
        self.view.alpha = 1
        fadeInThenOut(label: label, delay: 0)
    }
```

Now you don't need that code in **`ViewDidAppear`**.

Your whole code should look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fadeText), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

func fadeInThenOut(label : UILabel, delay: TimeInterval) {
    UILabel.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: delay, options: [UILabel.AnimationOptions.autoreverse, UILabel.AnimationOptions.repeat], animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        print("done")
    })

}

@objc func fadeText() {
    self.view.alpha = 1
    fadeInThenOut(label: textLabel, delay: 0)
}
```

Updated:
The above code animates self.view, not the textLabel. If you want to animate the label only then change `self.view.alpha` into `self.textLabel.alpha` inside both `fadeInThenOut()` and `fadeText()`